# Exchange 2007 Distribution List with External Addresses

Tags: email, exchange-2007, distribution-lists

I have set up a mail enabled distribution list but cannot assign an external e-mail address, it only accepts addresses in the GAL. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 4):

You can't just add external address to a distribution list as Exchange only allows you to add AD Objects (Mailboxes, Distribution Lists, Contacts etc) to distribution list. You need to create contact objects for your external email addresses. You can then add these contacts to your distribution list.